# Green / yellow negative scans

Tags: film, medium-format

New to this forum and I looked all over but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. 
All my negatives the scans were looking great and just out of the blue, the scans starting churning out these scans with a green/yellow cast.
Attaching a photo here but this photo was overexposed by 1 stop and was lit entirely by the sun. 
Is this a film problem (poorly stored), a developing chemical issue, or is it a camera issue?
Please, i'm going crazy trying to figure this out. :(

Thank you for all your help in advance !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmAVs.jpg

Comment: Does the entire roll have the same problem or only some frames?

Comment: Are there any color temperature settings in the scanner?

Comment: Thank you, Xenoid for the response !
It's consistent throughout the roll and several rolls.
I am currently scanning with the epson V550
and there are color curves that you can adjust but they seem to be really off even when I adjust the colors. :/ It doesn't look "genuine" for lack of a better word.
I haven't had problems before. :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the original image was exposed under a florescent light source. You can apply a correction using your photo editor. Florescent lamps output a non-continuous spectrum. Yellow-green is the normal for these lamps.

Comment: Hello Alan !
Thank you so much for your response.
I suspected that too but this was lit entirely by sunlight as per what I wrote.
All lights indoors were off.